# A book about a young boy climbing a hill ("Up _ Hill")

Tags: identification-request

In 3rd, 4th, or 5th grade, my language arts teacher assigned our class to read a book called "Up _ Hill" (so, I'm guessing the book is targeted towards younger/preteen audiences). All I can really remember about the book's plot is that the main character is a young boy, and there's a nearby mysterious hill that he wants to climb. As for what I remember about the title, I am almost certain that the title was of the form "Up [name of the hill, which I don't remember] Hill". Whenever I try to think of the name, though, the only things that pop up are the words "Knox" and "Knockturn". Knockturn's likely from Harry Potter (Knockturn alley), so I don't think that's right. "Up Knox Hill" doesn't seem to return any relevant search results.

Summary:

- English book (novel) about a young boy climbing a nearby, mysterious hill. I read it around 8 years ago, in school (specifically, I think in 4th grade; definitely somewhere from 3rd to 5th grade).
- The title is of the form "Up [something] Hill", and I have a vague impression that the hill's name is similar to the word Knox.
- Book is likely targeted towards younger or preteen audiences.
- Book's appearance: handheld, the area was about average, but I do remember that it was a little thin.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You've already provided some good details here, like when you read it and the language and target audience. Just in case you haven't already seen it, let me drop a link to the [ID tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) which has a checklist to help jog memories of ID askers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I found the book. It is *Knee-Knock Rise* by Natalie Babbitt, first published in 1970.

[The summary from Goodreads:](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/444330)

> From the moment young Egan arrives in Instep, he senses the spell cast over the villagers by the Megrimum--the mysterious something that lurks on the mist-wreathed peak of Kneeknock Rise. Everyone shudders in horror--delicious horror--whenever the Megrimum's unearthly wail floats down to the village. Before long, Egan is climbing the Rise to find a practical explanation for those wails.

To match the the descriptions in the question:

> - English book (novel) about a young boy climbing a nearby, mysterious hill. I read it around 8 years ago, in school (specifically, I think in 4th grade; definitely somewhere from 3rd to 5th grade).

The book is tagged for "Children, Middle Grade, Young Adult, Juvenile", so this definitely fits the time in life when it was first read.

> - The title is of the form "Up [something] Hill", and I have a vague impression that the hill's name is similar to the word Knox.

Knox into Kneeknock certainly fits the bill and the Hill part was correct.

> - Book is likely targeted towards younger or preteen audiences.

See above.

> - Book's appearance: handheld, the area was about average, but I do remember that it was a little thin.

The books is 118 pages which fairly short for the targeted demographic.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to include details about how this book matches/doesn't match the question, for the benefit of future searchers?